# Closed-contour integral of a derivative

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, complex-integration, residue-calculus

Suppose a function $f(z)$ is single-valued everywhere and holomorphic inside a closed contour $C$, except for one pole. The derivative $ g(z) = \frac{ \partial f}{\partial z}$  also has the same pole. I have a naive question about the integral

$$ \int_C dz  g(z) $$

This is the integral around a closed contour of the derivative of a single valued function, so it should be zero. But if done with the residues it should be nonzero because of the pole inside $C$.

So is it zero or not?

Comment: Why would it be $0$? Maybe you are talking about Stokes theorem ?

Comment: The Residue Theorem only picks up on *simple* poles. The pole for the derivative is no longer simple.

Comment: But that's not true, even the wikipedia page on residues gives the formula for poles of any order.

Comment: @Jennifer, sorry, I was being rather sloppy in my comment. I should have referred to poles with nonzero residue (which simple poles have, but derviatives of holomorphic functions with poles do not).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot say that that integral is non-zero simply because there is a pole. For example the integral of $\frac 1 {z^{2}}$ over the unit circle is $0$. Answer: YES, the integral is $0$.